# How to resolve "Network host is busy; will retry in 30 seconds"?

Tags: 11.10, networking, printing

I have added a network printer, a Konica Minolta C253, via cups by its IP (`http://10.0.0.42`) under the `http://localhost:631/` cups webfrontend on an Ubuntu 11.10 client.

I used the documented `KOC353U.ppd` in the process.

I was able to print exactly one page.

Afterwards, all I get in the printer's status is the message: "Network host '10.0.0.42' is busy; will retry in 30 seconds".

What is the problem here and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by switching to the lpd protocol. Socket lead to a [broken pipe problem.](http://p-s.co.nz/wordpress/solving-ubuntu-printer-broken-pipe-problem-docuprint-c525a/)

So I changed the connection to:

`lpd://10.0.0.42/queue`

Answer (score 2):

don't use ipp.

use "socket://###.###.###.##:port#/" for your  printer instead.

port # maybe 9100 or 631

**Reason**: The first specifications of IPP lacked of some important details. This allowed Microsoft to implement it in a their own way. The result was that printer manufacturer had to decide how to do their IPP support the way Microsoft does.

Therefore you should use a different protocol, the socket protocol.

Comment: This got me in the right direction. Yet via socket I got a broken pipe error. lpd was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: ok, thats good.